# YouTube fullscreen not displaying

Tags: embed, youtube

For some reason YouTube videos in my website do not get the fullscreen button, even if I added the parameter `allowFullScreen` set to true both in the object and embed tag.

Here's an example page: http://www.indievault.it/2011/11/09/indie-vault-alla-games-week-2011-online-la-video-gallery/

Just take a quick look at the source. The `allowFullScreen` param is there, but the button won't show. Here's an excerpt from the code in that page:

```
<object width="540" height="325"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/dvYQhJwwkgA"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/dvYQhJwwkgA" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="540" height="325"></embed </object>
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me

```
<object width="540" height="325"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/dvYQhJwwkgA?version=3&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/dvYQhJwwkgA?version=3&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="540" height="325" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed></object>​
```

Comment: Did this work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your code with this one:

```
<iframe title="YouTube video player" 
              width="540" height="325" 
              src="http://www.youtube.com/v/dvYQhJwwkgA?rel=0"
              frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

Comment: Tried it, but still no fullscreen button... any other idea?

Comment: Plus it does not work on iOS.